# how to join table using condition based on column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, case

My data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see I have duplicate `Premium` of $41.
If I say in my `JOIN` condition:

```
` LEFT OUTER JOIN Catalytic_vw_AggregateScheduleUniqueGUID agg ON agg.QuoteGuid = dbo.tblQuotes.QuoteGUID AND agg.guid = CL.CompanylocationGUID
            AND   agg.policyNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Then I won't see `NULL` value in `PolicyNumberFromRater` column.
 But I dont want to see NULL only for particular `LineGUID`, not for all of them.

Basically I want to say: use condition `AND agg.policyNumber IS NOT NULL` only for `LineGUID = CF144437...`
But if its gonna be other `LineGUID` then I DO want to see `NULL` in `PolicyNumberFromRater.

How can I do that when I am joining tables together?

The table that contain `LineGUID` is `tbl.Quotes` which is also could be found in a `JOIN`.

Here is my complete `JOIN`

```
 select PolicyNumber
    FROM       tblFin_Invoices INV 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQuotes ON INV.QuoteID = tblQuotes.QuoteID
                    INNER JOIN tblFin_InvoiceDetails INVD ON INV.InvoiceNum = INVD.InvoiceNum 
                    INNER JOIN dbo.tblQuoteDetails ON dbo.tblQuotes.QuoteGUID = dbo.tblQuoteDetails.QuoteGuid AND tblQuoteDetails.CompanyLineGuid = CF144437-F128-4B77-AC19-877247347D02
INVD.CompanyLineGuid    
                    LEFT OUTER  JOIN dbo.tblCompanyLines ON dbo.tblQuoteDetails.CompanyLineGuid = dbo.tblCompanyLines.CompanyLineGUID 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblCompanyLocations AS CL ON dbo.tblCompanyLines.CompanyLocationGUID = CL.CompanyLocationGUID 
                LEFT OUTER  JOIN tblCompanyLocations ON tblQuotes.CompanyLocationGuid = tblCompanyLocations.CompanyLocationGUID
    ---------/*This is where I need the condition*/
                LEFT OUTER JOIN Catalytic_vw_AggregateScheduleUniqueGUID agg ON agg.QuoteGuid = dbo.tblQuotes.QuoteGUID AND agg.guid = CL.CompanylocationGUID
                AND agg.policyNumber IS NOT NULL 
   --(use "AND agg.policyNumber IS NOT NULL" only for LineGUID = CF144437...)      
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN         tblSubmissionGroup ON tblQuotes.SubmissionGroupGuid = tblSubmissionGroup.SubmissionGroupGUID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN         tblUsers ON INV.UnderwriterUserGUID = tblUsers.UserGUID
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN         tblClientOffices ON tblQuotes.QuotingLocationGuid = tblClientOffices.OfficeGUID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  tblInsureds ON tblSubmissionGroup.InsuredGuid = tblInsureds.InsuredGuid
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  lstPolicyTypes ON tblQuotes.PolicyTypeID = lstPolicyTypes.PolicyTypeID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this, When LineGUID is other value and agg.policyNumber isnull, the condition will be ''!='*'(True)

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Catalytic_vw_AggregateScheduleUniqueGUID agg ON agg.QuoteGuid = dbo.tblQuotes.QuoteGUID AND agg.guid = CL.CompanylocationGUID
            AND  ISNULL(agg.policyNumber,'')!=CASE WHEN LineGUID = 'CF144437...' THEN '' ELSE '*' END
```

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to deal with the situation you described, namely handling records where all columns are duplicate except for `PolicyNumberFromRater`, where one or more records may have `NULL`, then I think you can just aggregate those `NULL` values away using `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT MAX(PolicyNumberFromRater) AS PolicyNumberFromRater,
       LineGUID,
       Premium,
       Carrier,
       -- other columns
FROM tblFin_Invoices INV 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblQuotes
    ON INV.QuoteID = tblQuotes.QuoteID
-- other joins
GROUP BY LineGUID,
         Premium,
         Carrier,
         -- all other columns in SELECT except for PolicyNumberFromRater
```